# Nginx memory consumption gradaully increase and reaches to 100%

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nginx-config, google-cloud-filestore

We are nginx in kubernetes(GKE). Nginx is streaming files from google filestore which is mounted on the nginx pod.

Nginx memory consumptions starts to increase as soon as we start streaming those file. Eventually it reaches to 100% over a period of day or two and pods gets restarted. We are have not been able to figure out what could be the probable issue which causing memory consumption to go 100%.

Below is the nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
}
```

Google file store is mounted mounted at

```
/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Applying the Requests and limits to the containers can make sure that memory utilization doesn't cross the limits applied. I.e Requests and limits are the mechanisms Kubernetes uses to control resources such as CPU and memory. Requests are what the container is guaranteed to get. If a container requests a resource, Kubernetes will only schedule it on a node that can give it that resource. Limits, on the other hand, make sure a container never goes above a certain value. The container is only allowed to go up to the limit, and then it is restricted.

Comment: Refer [Requests and limits](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits) and [Specify a memory request and a memory limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#specify-a-memory-request-and-a-memory-limit) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! We have appropriate resource limit applied for the pod. The curious case is why memory consumption increases, is there some memory leak which is happening we are not quite sure.

Comment: Can you add more details regarding your configuration and is any other workload running in that pod and I have few question 1.How did you get to know that pods have completed 100 percent of memory 2.Did you get error message regarding 100 percent utilization of memory?

Comment: We dont have anything else running on the same pod. We have prometheusrules and alerts configured.

Comment: Few more questions 1.What is the Present version of GKE cluster? 2.Did you encounter this issue for the first time or had this issue before too?
3.Can you try configuring nginx on another node and see if you observe the same behavior on the new node and Can you provide events and logs of the pods which are reaching 100 percent utilization. To get this info we can go to the navigation menu in GCP Console here go to and in GKE go to clusters, in cluster go to node and in node go to pod. Here you see event details and logs of that particular pod.

Comment: Seem to have found the issue.
Nginx in our case performs heavy read/write this causes the kernel to cache. Kubelet includes active page cache as pod memory although nginx process would only utlilize 48 Mb.